# delete pattern at least 5 numbers non consecutive

Tags: linux, grep, regular-expression

I have a file with about 7 million passwords with mixed Lower Upper digits

all have the same length 8 symbols

I want to remove the passwords than contain 5 or more digits not necessary consecutive:

Example:

```
A0s123tf - OK
tttttttt - OK
096545aZ - Remove
Z0123456 - Remove
z445Jz55 - Remove -> fail
```

if I do for example:

```
grep -E -v '[0-9]{5,} myfile
```

fail with the last word because the numbers aren't consecutive.

What is the correct regex for this case?

Comment: so.. `/(.*[0-9].*){5}/`?

Comment: `grep -E -v '(.*[0-9]){5}' file`  or `grep -E -v '([0-9].*){5}' file` should be enough.

Comment: On a tangential note, **someone has done some *very bad things* if these are actual passwords.** They are not hashed, they are shorter than the absolute minimum which should be required these days, and they have a counter-productive format restriction (all of these points have been discussed at great length elsewhere). If this is related to a production system you're working on, you'd better get someone familiar with proper password handling in ASAP. Someone is at least morally, and possibly criminally, negligent.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need it to be a regexp, or can you pipe? A hacky way to do it would be to look for 5 digits

```
$ cat j
A0s123tf
tttttttt
096545aZ
Z0123456
z445Jz55
$ grep -E -v '\d.*\d.*\d.*\d.*\d' j
A0s123tf
tttttttt
$
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, search for the inverse; since they're each eight characters long, require 4 non-digits:

```
grep -E '[^[:digit:]].*[^[:digit:]].*[^[:digit:]].*[^[:digit:]]' myfile
```

or condensed a bit:

```
grep -E '([^[:digit:]].*){4}' myfile
```

Comment: Running some timing tests on 7 million randomly generated 8-char passwords, I'm getting around 7.7 sec for the 4 * not-a-digit search, and around 6.5 sec for 5 * is-a-digit search. Couldn't tell you why, though.